# .gitignore is out of date in git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I wanted to do

```
git svn dcommit
```

but I am getting

```
Merge conflict during commit: File or directory 
'.gitignore' is out of date; try updating: resource
 out of date; try updating at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 922
```

how to update from svn repo only the `.gitignore`?

Comment: Have you tried `git svn rebase`?

Comment: yes Barend, I it's bringing some conflits in merging :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have uncommitted local changes to .gitignore - you will need to get them out of the way before you can update from the svn remote using `git svn rebase`.

Use

```
git stash
```

to temporarily hide your local changes, then use `git svn rebase` to get the latest version from svn. Next you can restore your temporary changes using

```
git stash pop
```

Git will report any conflicts which you can fix locally or if you decide you don't need your local changes anymore use:

```
git checkout -- .gitignore
```

to overwrite your local .gitignore file with the one fetched from the repository.

Comment: It updates from your default local branch so you need to fetch the updated version from the svn remote first. See updated answer